# Cannot link index.html file to style.css file in another folder

Tags: html, css, simplehttpserver, npm-live-server

I'm trying to link my style.css file to my index.html file. Both files are located in separate folders.

Folder structure:

/parent

- /src/index.html
- /css/style.css

Codes that I have tried using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

The same error I keep getting in the terminal:

> GET /css/style.css 404 1.542 ms - 152

I'm using VS Code with live-server.

Note: When I put my index.html file outside src folder in the parent folder. The path href="css/style.css" works.

Comment: Try ../../css/style.css

Comment: @Albeis Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) in the Root `/parent`, then navigate to `/src/index.html`.
If you start in the directory containing `index.html` you can Not go upwards.

Answer (score -1):

Your href should look like this: href="style.css"